# Read-only entities using Spring Data

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I would like to avoid Hibernate's dirty-checking on my fetched entities.
Using the Hibernate API you can do this with the following method: [Query#setReadOnly(boolean)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setReadOnly(boolean)).

Can I achieve the same thing using Spring Data?

The transaction itself modifies other entities, so marking the transaction as read-only in not an option.

Comment: Just make the transaction read only.

Comment: That's not appropriate in my case. Updating the question..

Comment: Then use `@QueryHint` and set `org.hibernate.readOnly` to `true`.

Comment: The hint is working, but if I load associated entities through the selected ones, those are added to the persistence context. Can I exclude those as well?